# jQuery-file-uploader with Rails 4.0 Nested Resource

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, jquery-file-upload

I have an app that has a Gallery that has_many :gallery_images

I followed Ryan Bates [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload) and I got multiple images to upload. The problem im running into is geting the create.js.erb file to auto refresh the page. Here's what I got.

**gallery.rb**

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gallery_images, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**gallery_images.rb**

```
class GalleryImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  has_attached_file :image, 
                    :styles => { :original => "1600x1600>",
                                 :thumb => "100x100#" }, 
                                 :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

  validates_attachment :image,
                       :presence => true,
                       :content_type => { :content_type => ['image/jpeg'] }
end
```

**gallery_images_controller.rb**

```
class GalleryImagesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    if signed_in?
      @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find(params[:gallery_id])
      @image = @gallery.gallery_images.create(gallery_image_params)
      redirect_to gallery_path(@gallery)
    else
      @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find(params[:gallery_id])
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in to add an image."
      session[:return_to] = gallery_path(@gallery)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find(params[:gallery_id])
    @image = @gallery.gallery_images.find(params[:id])
    @image.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Image removed."
    redirect_to gallery_path(@gallery)
  end

  private

    def gallery_image_params
      params.require(:gallery_image).permit(:image)
    end
end
```

**views/galleries/show.html.erb**

```
<div id="links">
  <%= render @gallery.gallery_images %>
</div>

<% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
  <%= render "gallery_images/form" %>
<% end %>
```

**views/gallery_images/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@gallery, @gallery.gallery_images.new], html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :image, "Upload Image:" %>
  <%= f.file_field :image, multiple: true, name: "gallery_image[image]" %>      
<% end %>
```

**javascripts/gallery_images.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#new_gallery_image').fileupload()
  dataType: "script"
```

**views/gallery_images/create.js.erb**

```
<% if @image.new_record? %>
  alert("Failed to upload image");
<% else %>
  $("#links").append("<%= j render(@image) %>");
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have any errors, or just nothing happens?

Comment: No errors, it uploads all the files and with no loading bars.

Answer (score 0):

So do you need a remote: true, or a respond_with :javascript block in the controller?

Looks like it's just going to redirect back to the page, and never actually use the create.js.erb template.